# Error 1022 "Can't write duplicate key in table" in MYSQL. Strange part is other I have created other tables with the same way

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am using MSQL Workbench 8.0. I have a schema and I am creating a new table using a foreign key **ProductId**. Other tables that were created before with the same foreign key worked fine. However, with this table, I am getting this strange error mentioned below:

> The operation failed: There was an error while applying the SQL script
> to the database. ERROR 1022: Can't write; duplicate key in the table
> 'Ing_BuildSpec'

The SQL Statement I have created:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `iqadb`.`Ing_BuildSpec` (
  `IngId` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Name` VARCHAR(50) NULL,
  `Quantity` INT NULL,
  `Weight` INT NULL,
  `Tolerance` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `Equipment` VARCHAR(50) NULL,
  `ProductId` INT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`IngId`),
  INDEX `ProductId_idx` (`ProductId` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `ProductId`
    FOREIGN KEY (`ProductId`)
    REFERENCES `iqadb`.`Products` (`ProductId`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION);
```

Could you please tell me what is the problem. I have checked other threads and I tried their way but it didn't work, hence I am asking a new question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:  We cannot have multiple **Foreign Key Names** with the same name. I have changed the name and it worked.

"**[image: Foreign Key Names]**"